# How can i build like this widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, widget

I have a task and i need to build like this widget
you can see the video in link
[video in googel drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1URzmYzpfEz5brdiJ6TJYI5kqyd1E1R0f/view?usp=sharing)
thanks.

this task is very important for me.

Comment: Hey mate, Please review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimum reproduceable code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the things you've tried. If you're looking for a tutorial, please consider other resources like google or reddit instead.

Comment: sorry, either provider the requested info above, or if you do not have any code, try other online resources. Stackoverflow is for focused Q&A and not for open ended opinion based questions. It is unlikely you'll get any good answers if you cannot provide the code you're working on.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/buttons_tabbar try this package, with some edits it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can custom `indicator` of Tabbar, use `indicator:` and edits it

Try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  const Profile({super.key});

  @override
  State<Profile> createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            isScrollable: true,
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            indicatorPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(7),
            splashBorderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            indicator: ShapeDecoration(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18)),
                color: Colors.purpleAccent.shade200
            ),
            labelColor: Colors.purple,
            overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color?>(Colors.transparent),
            tabs: const [
              Tab(
                icon: Text('Helllo'),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Text('Wowowowow'),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Text('Hi'),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Text('Long text Long text'),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Text('Short'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My result:

[image]